# Inconsistent "Quality standards"?

Tags: discussion

I wanted to ask this question:

> Ich fand "Heftfolgen" als der Name eine Mappes mit digitalen Büchern. Was bedeutet es? (Das Wörterbuch hilft nicht)

Maybe not completely grammatically correct, but a clear and complete question IMO. SE wouldn't accept it though because

> "This question body does not meet our quality standards." etc.etc

WTH? I added some insignificant text and then it seemed OK. Is One of the "quality standards" the length of the body text? Also, I wanted to repeat it with a new question, same body text, to make a screenshot of the complete warning message for here, and this time SE *did* accept it.

This is clearly inconsistent behavior, but my main question is: "Why was my first question refused?" What are the "quality standards"?

Answer (score 2):

Our quality standards are outlined in the [Help Center](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error):

> - A clear title.
> - A reasonable explanation of what your question is. Add as much detail as you can.
> - Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem.
> - Correct use of English spelling and grammar to the best of your ability.

Based on this a computer-generated algorithm was developed but there is no indication that details will be released (this also to prevent abuse). See more here:

- [What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

Because it is a robot who judges our posts we will have to live with it being far from perfect. Nevertheless this automatism incredibly helps to keep poor questions off the site and was a great achievement to improve overall quality of all Stack Exchange sites.

Whenever we see this message we should therefore not be angry on a robot but just go on and try to add some more bits, examples, quotes or whatever we feel it may help to make our questions better. It will not hurt if we do so.

If in doubt, don't hesitate to [ask in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/499/german-language) for ideas on how to improve a question.

Just as a side note: there is a similar apporach for answers, which can be posted (we all have seen such poor answers) but will get an automatic "low quality" flag from the "Community Moderator"-robot to make these posts appear in the review queue.